Ubuntu freezing on my ThinkPad L530

I'm experiencing this problem since I installed Lubuntu on my ThinkPad L530 from Lenovo, in june 2023.
It was Lubuntu 22.04 LTS initially.
At first the computer froze (generally after 7 days without restarting the PC), and I had a popup in my bios saying "the non volatile variable is about full, press F1 for settings", and had to save the changes (even tho I didnt do any), and then flush the content of efivars starting with dump-*
I thought it happened because the variable was progressively accumulating dumps so I made a cronjob to clean them every minute. No success, it still happened in the exact same manner, after some days, generally 4-7.
I got bored of this problem so I reinstalled in MBR mode and disabled EFI from the bios.
I still get the freezes but this time it's not mentioning any memory being full in the bios, it just freezes and I have to reboot.
I got suspicious about the version 22.04 and upgraded the pc to 24.04 LTS with the latest Linux kernel.
I still get the freezes, in the same manner: after some days not doing a full reboot, some minutes after my laptop goes out of sleep mode, it freezes.
I also played with some settings in the bios about sleep mode with no success.
What I can tell is the PC was not overheating, it was even colder than usual because it was just after going out of sleep mode.
The ram was not full, I was not doing anything special, just basic utilisation of my PC. Swap was also very far from being full, the laptop has 16 GB of RAM and 6 GB of Swap on an SSD.
The SSD is clean, checked with GSmartControl and smartctl.
I even replaced it with another one after cloning the disk with dd and it still happens

I updated the system to this version:6.8.0-41-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug  2 20:41:06 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Edit: now the system doesn't just freeze but performs a reboot after it freezes for a second.


Edit 2: 10 dec 2024: 

I have collected kernel logs using journalctl -k -b -1 and -2 because -1 contained only very limited logs, but -2 contained all the logs starting at the last reboot date (2 dec. 2024).
The last time I did a real reboot of my system was on the 2 of december. The crash happened the 10 at 15H52.
If you want me to post the logs, let me know how to do it. 

Your details are unclear; and I wonder if you're having a hardware (cap) issue?  If it's hardware, you'll find the same on any OS. You mention releases (22.04) but not which kernel stack you were using, as 22.04 is a LTS thus you had kernel stack choice (with Lubuntu the default is set by install media; both GA & HWE ISOs existed; for some older devices I find the older GA kernel stack is better). By freezes does the system eventually resume? ie. thrashing? Did you create or increase swap? (makes a huge difference on low RAM) https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/swap-and-lubuntu-faq/2591

Ok I checked yesterday both the Motheboard and the Ram (in the bios, using Lenovo integrated checks), all the tests passed.
I have the kernel 6.8.0-38, previously had 6.5-0-25 I think, at least it was 6.5 something using 22.04.
I didn't increase the swap because in normal utilization I have 4 GB unused and my swap is far from being full.
And no the system does not resume, I let it wait for 5 minutes it stayed frozen, I didn't try to wait for an hour or so, but I don't think it would have resumed if I had waited longer.

I'm experiencing a similar problem as your's, on a DELL lattitude 5520 with 8Gb ram, on lubuntu 22.04 LTS since a week, but only on batteries. No worries (for the moment) when plugged.
Since the first install of lubuntu 22.04 i have always a message saying that batteries manager have crashed and will not be reloaded before the next restart. it was the only problem (no more batterie state in the status bar) for more than a year. Now, i've got this message, and, in the next minutes, the computer freeze with no solution to restore state (only 5 second on start button to restart).
i have a dual boot (windows 10) and no worries when working on win10 unplugged, even using big softwares. I don't think it's the hardware.
My conclusion for the moment : I think that it could be a problem associated with battery manager. Maybe it can be replaced by another
have you got a difference between working "plugged" an working with batteries ?
ps : i have spend initially some times to make hibernate mode working in order to be secure if batteries became too low. hibernation works properly (in a dedicated swap partition)

No battery issues, no difference if charging or not

OK it's not the same problem. The mine has been solved by re-installing with lubuntu 24.04..
It does not explain why the computer was freezing, but it works now. Good Luck to find a solve to your problem

Ah also my trackpad freezes sometimes, maybe it has to do with that.
